# Is is possible to specify my own Message-Id email header when sending using Mandrill?

Tags: node.js, email, gmail, mandrill, messageid

I am sending emails using Mandrill and I want to set the Message-ID myself. I see now an ID like this:

```
Message-Id: <30152892.20150311183809.55008b919f0c49.69649774@mail132-29.atl131.mandrillapp.com>
```

What I am trying to do is to find out why Gmail does not group messages sent from Mandrill into conversations. Maybe this has to do with the `Message-ID` and `In-Reply-To` headers.

I am using the [Mandrill Node API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.nodejs.html#method=send-template) and the `sendTemplate` function has an option to set `headers`. But this is not working because Mandrill apparently overwrites my ID.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can set your own, but you will want to be sure that it follows the appropriate format for a message id. We won't override your id as long as it appears to be valid, but if it's not formatted correctly, we'll overwrite it.

Comment: Thanks Kaitlin, I confirm! I initially sent the ID without the surrounding `<...>` and that must habe been the reason why Mandrill replaced it.

Comment: @kaitlin Is it not possible to get the `Message-ID` while sending email? I know we get a `_id` field but Message-ID is what is used in the `In-Reply-To`.

Comment: I am trying to identify an inbound mail as a reply to a previously sent mail. But `_id` is not available in the reply to identify this reply. Something similar to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512212/set-message-id-with-mandrill-for-bulk-emails

Comment: This just seems like a HORRIBLE idea. Ugh. Why can't you guys just give us the message-id when we send. It *is* available in the `diag` response but it would be really nice to just get it as a distinct value

Comment: It's only available in the `diag` response in webhooks such as `open` webhook and not even in `send` :-(

Comment: This is so frustrating. Why can't you just give me the `message-id`. Now I have to waste time reading RFC and wondering if generating my own message-id could possibly have any effect on deliverability or other unforseen problems. Note: MailGun (your competitor) does return the 'message-id' field on send http://blog.mailgun.com/tracking-replies-in-mailgun-or-any-other-email/

Comment: It looks like AppleMail generates a GUID + domain name. eg. `70436b10-cb4a-4426-9d0a-53ff65b0e1df@example.com` (where you put your actual sending domain). So that would be the simplest approach. I can't for the life of me understand why Mandrill can't just give me the ID, but oh well this will hopefully do. As long as there are no deliverability issues with not using mandrill's original ID