# Set Message-Id with Mandrill for bulk emails

Tags: mandrill

I am sending emails to lists of contacts based on templates using Mandrill. I would like to track if the contacts have replied to my email and, to do so, I would like to check whether the `Message-Id` of my sent emails appears in the `In-Reply-To` header field of new messages.

The problem is that I have to generate and set the `Message-Id` manually since Mandrill only gives me their internal `_id`. However, since I am sending emails to various contacts at the same time, I set `preserve_recipients` to `false`. But then I can only set one `Message-Id`, which will therefore become *not globally unique*.

Here is an example JSON that I'm sending:

```
{
"from_email": "itsme@email.com",
"from_name": "Its Me",
"headers": {"Message-Id": ["<20150528161426.4265.93582@email.com>"]},
"subject": "Thesubject",
"text": "Thebody",
"to": [
    {
        "email": "john@email.com",
        "name": "John",
        "type": "to"
    },
    {
        "email": "patrick@email.com",
        "name": "Patrick",
        "type": "to"
    }
],
"preserve_recipients": false
```

}

In this case, two messages will be sent, but they'll have the same `Message-Id`. If I don't set it, Mandrill will automatically assign one, but then I can't retrieve it.

Any idea what I could do ? Maybe my whole approach is incorrect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up looping over all the recipients and generating a new `Message-Id` at each iteration and send one email at a time. Probably not optimal since I'm not using Mandrill bulk capability, but at least now I can store the email id.

```
import email
import mandrill

mandrill_client = mandrill.Mandrill('YOUR_MANDRILL_KEY')

for recipient in recipients:
    # Generate RFC 2822-compliant Message-ID header
    message_id = email.Utils.make_msgid()
    m = {
        "headers": {"Message-Id": [message_id],
        "from_email": "itsme@email.com",
        "from_name": "Its Me",
        "subject": "The subject",
        "text": "The body",
        "to": [{"email": recipient["email"],
                "name": recipient["name"],
                "type": "to"}],
        "track_clicks": True,
        "track_opens": True
    }
    result = mandrill_client.messages.send(message=m)
```

Comment: Could you post your `make_msgid()` function or give a little detail about how you created the message-ID? I couldn't find the format of it in the Docs

Comment: Sure. It is made using Python's built-in `email` library and more specifically the [`utils.make_msgid()`](http://doc.hc2.ch/python-2.7.9-docs-html/library/email.util.html#email.utils.make_msgid) function, which creates [RFC 2822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822.html)-compliant Message-ID header.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From [mandrill documentation](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html) you can retrieve the _id from the return value of the message.

[image: doc]

Comment: I know, but this information is only internal to Mandrill and will be lost when I receive the reply of an email.

Comment: Then use webhooks, I use them for my mailing system and they work great

Comment: There seems to be a useful answer from mandrill support: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29010839/4940233

Comment: I'm using webhooks to get the _sent_, _open_ and _clicked_ status, but there is no _replied_ event, right ? Yes, I used the Mandrill support answer to set the `Message-Id` header field, but in the case of bulk emails, one id will be set for all messages, which is not a good idea...

Comment: You can use Inbound email webhooks https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583197-Inbound-Email-Processing-Overview

Comment: Thanks. I can access the `Message-Id` and most importantly `In-Reply-To` header fields, but when I send a message via mandrill, I don't get the original `Message-Id` so I cannot compare it with the reply I received.

Comment: then what is the point of In-Reply-To if it doesnt have the Message-Id of the original message?

Comment: @FranLupión it does! The problem is that Mandrill doesn't give us that header when it initially sends the email. Note: MailGun does http://blog.mailgun.com/tracking-replies-in-mailgun-or-any-other-email/

Comment: The Mandrill _id is different from the RFC 2822 Message ID, hence the issue.