# Mandrill inbound: Reply mail not adding Metadata or an Id of the outbound mail

Tags: node.js, email, mailchimp, mandrill

I have a domain through which I have both Outbound and Inbound mails being processed.

Now, I have some Metadata associated with outbound mail like so:

```
"metadata": {
            "leadId": "abcxyz123"
        },
```

But when a user replies to that mail, there is no metadata present in the Inbound (and hence I cannot get a `leadId` in the reply). Even the [docs](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583197-Inbound-Email-Processing-Overview) do not mention any metadata.

Is there no way to have an identifier of the previous mail in this reply mail?

Another option would be to track the `_id` generated by Mandrill when sending the outbound message but the problem is, for the inbound reply, Mandrill returns a `Message-Id` field in the reply header which is completely different from `_id`.

Others have talked about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30662490/804503) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29010839/804503). They mention that `Message-Id` should be overrode with the proper format but this is not documented anywhere. I am not sure what the proper format is.

Here are a couple of sample `Message-Id` in the header of some replies:

```
<30903104.20160624191624.576d87086bd4e0.31443987@mail187-3.suw11.mandrillapp.com>
<30903104.20160624221759.576db1976357f9.40139186@mail136-9.atl41.mandrillapp.com>
```

I would assume tracking some Id/metadata of the original mail in a reply mail would be a common scenario. Is this not the case? Should I be doing something differently?

Answer (score 0):

I too was unable to get `_id` on inbound reply emails sent to Mandrill's server. My use case was storing the email's id to later look up the full message's content. I settled on storing the entire email's content and having a job to wipe the data after 30 days.